Anyone knows how to remove this deadbolt/lock without visible screw?
Here is the picture, would like to change it without damage to it:


Do you also have a picture from the other side of the door? Can you confirm that this faceplate is hanging from a kind of hook at the top?

Looks like the top may have a tab that can be used to release the metal-looking cover.  Maybe there's a fastener under there that can be used to remove the deadbolt?

I figured it out. So, that black button is a hook. You need to press it and, simultaneously, apply some force to lift the outer cover.

It looks like there may be a set screw on the top oof the knob. If there is loosen the screw (Possibly a very small allen or a jewlers slotted head). Remove the knob then pry the trim plate off with a small screw driver. This should give you acesss to the mounting hardware.
